# Cannot compile references?

Tags: bibliographies

under latex i created the `bibliography.bib` file :

```
@book{yang2018optimization,
    title={Optimization techniques and applications with examples},
    author={Yang, Xin-She},
    year={2018},
    publisher={John Wiley \& Sons}
}
```

The main text document looks like :

```
\documentclass[notitlepage]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage[left=0.3in,right=0.3in,top=0.3in,bottom=0.5in]{geometry}

\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{caption}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{figures/}}

\usepackage{longtable}

%\usepackage{algorithm}

\usepackage{algorithmic}

\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage[ ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{ifoddpage}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{authblk} 
 
 
\begin{document}


bla bla bla ~\cite{yang2018optimization}.


\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{bibliography.bib}
\end{document}
```

After compiling , the references dosen't appair. I tried to use the bibtex citations from google scholar but nothing worked.

[image]

Thank you a lot for help!

Comment: Note that the main.tex and bibliography.bib are in the same directory. I guessed that maybe the compiler isn't able to recognize where the bibliography.bib file actually exists.

Comment: After running LaTeX, have you also run BibTeX, followed by two more LaTeX runs?

Comment: @Mico , yes i tried but it doesn't worked !

Comment: I added a picture of the error in the post.

Comment: Please clarify what "I tried to use the bibtex citations from google scholar" entails. Does the file `\jobname.blg` contain error and/or warning messages? If so, what do they say?

Comment: Also try `\bibliography{bibliography}`i.e., without the extension/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(too long for a comment, hence posted as an answer).

Compiling the sample document shown below with LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX *twice more* yields the following output:

[image]

If you don't get this output, do check the log and blg files for warning and error messages.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{bibliography.bib}
@book{yang2018optimization,
    title={Optimization Techniques and Applications with Examples},
    author={Yang, Xin-She},
    year={2018},
    publisher={John Wiley~\& Sons},
}
\end{filecontents}
 
\begin{document}
\cite{yang2018optimization}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{bibliography.bib}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This isn't really an answer as there isn't really a problem. Both this and OP's question run without a problem for me...

Comment: Your code works in a separate .tex file but it fails when trying to integrate it in my main.tex document. it shows [?] in the citation place.

Comment: I think that maybe one of the packages i used is conflicting with the code.

Comment: @EladDen - Please re-read the disclaimer in the first line of my posting: "too long for a comment, hence posted as an answer".

Comment: @TouMou - If I add the rest of your preamble code back in, the formatted bibliography and the citation call-out work fine just the same.

Comment: @TouMou - You wrote in a comment, "it shows [?] in the citation place." In short, you have not run BibTeX -- at least not correctly. If you don't run BibTeX correctly and don't run LaTeX twice more after running BibTeX (correctly...), you're absolutely guaranteed to get `[?]` in lieu of a usable citation call-out.

Comment: @Mico , i know that is strange . but i created a new document tex and i tried to recompile my document with the same packages and actually it works fine.

Comment: The problem is know solved , i will just recompile the work in a the new.tex document and it's all ! Thank you all for the precious help !

Comment: @Mico , i used your code but it it reverses the order of citations. !!!!!

Comment: @TouMou - Please clarify what you mean by "it reverses the order of citations!!!!!" Are the entries really sorted in reverse alphabetical order, from Z to A? That would be something fairly unprecedented.

Comment: @Mico , yes exactly !

Comment: I resolved the issue , actually i should use \bibliographystyle{ieeetr}  instead of \bibliographystyle{plain} .

Comment: @TouMou - The `plain` bibliography style sorts entries alphabetically, from A to Z, by authors' surnames. The `unsrt`, `ieeetr`, and `IEEEtran` bibliography styles don't perform *any* sorting, meaning that the ordering of the entries in the formatted bibliography is the same as the order in which the entries are first `\cite`d in the body of the text.

Comment: Yes i understand now. I used the plain style after watching a video tutorial about latex citations without having awarness about what plain style acually do .

Comment: Thank you again @Mico for your valuable help & remarks !